Different Wayland/Xorg defaults in 24.04
I made a fresh install of 24.04 to 3 laptops, all similar with similar nvidia graphics card (different year model).
I saw that in two of them, gdm3 loads in using x11, while the other one gdm3 loads in wayland (checked with loginctl the gdm3 session at login screen).
All files seem to be identical in /usr/share/wayland-sessions and /usr/share/wayland-sessions, and also /etc/gdm3/custom.conf is as default in all of them with the WaylandEnable=false commented out.
I am quite curious about the difference as the 3 computers were installed from the same installation media and are quite similar (see specs below), and they all (I believe) preinstalled the nvidia drivers (as I selected the 3rd party checkbox).
I would also like to know about where this is set and what other differences there may be between the installations. Can anyone shed some light on why one computer would use Wayland in the login screen while the other two use Xorg?
More info about the three laptops:

Laptop 1: Dell precision 5530, Quadro P2000 4GB vram. Shows the "Ubuntu"/"Ubuntu on Wayland" option
Laptop 2: Dell precision 5560, RTX A2000 4GB vram. Shows the "Ubuntu"/"Ubuntu on Xorg" option
Laptop 3: Dell precision 557, RTX A2000 8GB vram. Shows the "Ubuntu"/"Ubuntu on Wayland" (the same options as in Laptop 1).

All laptops are running nvidia driver 560.35.03.
Update:
I believe this is set by the 61-gdm.rules.
As these are all hybrid laptops, I understand Wayland should be preferred, although there is another rule based on the nvidia driver version that should set xorg to preferred.
In the laptop that loads wayland in gdm3 login screen, the var/run/gdm3/custom.conf file is missing (while it's there in the others with the PreferredDisplayDriver=xorg setting there), so it seems the rule indeed trigger differently in Laptop 2.
Update 1:
I found that rebooting laptop 2 logs in with gdm3 preferring xorg, while booting from shut down prefers wayland. I couldn't find which rule fails in that case.

The weird one is that the newest laptop and the oldest have the "Ubuntu on Wayland" option, while the one in between having the "ubuntu on Xorg" was in the middle. That one has an RTX A2000 with 4GB of RAM, and the other has an RTX A2000 with 8GB (and the oldest a Quadro P2000). That's why I'm confused, and I would like to figure out what made the different in the menu names and so

Thanks, I edited word it better and added some more details.

Are they all using the same version of the Nvidia driver?

Yes, they are. Laptop 2 today on boot was showing it as in the other ones, after a reboot it went back to normal. It is not a problem as everything works, I am mainly curious to understand why the rule triggering is different. All are running gm3 version 46.0-2ubuntu1
